# How to properly configure dap-mode to debug c/c++?

Tags: emacs

I am new to emacs. Recently, I saw on the forum that the C language can be debugged using dap-mode, but when I configure dap-mode according to the official tutorial, there are always various errors at runtime. Would like to ask if anyone has successfully configured dap-mode so that the C language can be debugged. If so, can you post the full configuration for me to study，thanks

Comment: I am not sure if this is a valid question, questions here are not supposed to be seeking for recommendations.

Comment: you probably should show the errors and post some configurations from your config file.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, in fact, when I type `M-x dap-debug`, it prompts the following error: Warning (emacs): Initialize request failed: Could not create a target for a program '/home/fd/code_study/C/c_primer_plus/8/8.1/1.c': '/home/fd/code_study/C/c_primer_plus/8/8.1/1.c' doesn't contain any 'host' platform architectures: x86_64, i386. Disable showing Disable logging